# Study the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \sqrt[17]{5+ \frac1n} - \sqrt[17]{5}\right)^{a}q^n$ for $a>0$ and $q\in\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a problem with this task, because I think the most important is idea to do convergence of the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left( \sqrt[17]{5+ \frac{1}{n} } - \sqrt[17]{5}\right)^{\!a},
$$ 
but it is difficult for me because it is power $a$ and for $a=1$.

I can use claim about three series, but in this case I completely don't knew what can I do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. First show that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty\,}n\left(\sqrt[17]{5+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt[17]{5}\right)=\frac{\sqrt[17]{5}}{85},
$$
and hence
$$
\left(\sqrt[17]{5+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt[17]{5}\right)^a\approx \left(\frac{\sqrt[17]{5}}{85}\right)^an^{-a}
$$
Thus, we have convergence of the series if $|q|<1$, or $q=1$ and $a>1$, or $q=-1$ and $a>0$.

Comment: Ok, but if I have to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty\,}n\left(\sqrt[17]{5+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt[17]{5}\right)=\frac{\sqrt[17]{5}}{85}$ I should multiply by coupling $\left(\sqrt[17]{5+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt[17]{5}\right)$ but I think it is impossible for power $1/17$ - I can do it for example for $1/16$ but not for $1/17$

Comment: If I understand well, you need the following additional information:

Pulling out $\sqrt[17]{5}$

$\left(\sqrt[17]{5+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt[17]{5}\right)=\left(\sqrt[17]{5}\sqrt[17]{1+\frac{1}{5n}}-\sqrt[17]{5}\right)=\sqrt[17]{5}\left(\sqrt[17]{1+\frac{1}{5n}}-1\right)$

Using Bernoulli's inequality you receive an upper bound:

$\sqrt[17]{5}\left(\sqrt[17]{1+\frac{1}{5n}}-1\right)\le\sqrt[17]{5}\left({1+\frac{1}{85n}}-1\right)=\frac{\sqrt[17]{5}}{85n}$

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I need also lower limit, but I think the only possibility is $\ge \left(\sqrt[17]{5+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt[17]{5+\frac{1}{n^{b}}}\right)$ for $b>1$, but in this case I cannot show that the limit of this expression is $\frac{\sqrt[17]{5}}{85n}$ because here I also need 3 ranks so I should find an expression where the limit is obvious